# How to add click action on parent element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, element, parent

I have a directive

```
<child-div child-data="childData"></child-div>
```

I have requirement that I have to associate click action based on following case

1. if childData.view == true then associate click action on directive
2. if childData.view == false then associate action on its parent.

Problem is I am not able to get parent element of childDiv directive when condition 2 satisfy.

could any one please tell me how can I do this.
Thanks in Advance

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testDirectives')
.directive('childDiv', function ( $compile, $q){
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: {
        actionInstance: '=',
    },
    replace : true,
    templateUrl : 'template.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        status = isViewAssociatedWithAction();
        if(status){ //action on directive

            element.css('cursor', 'pointer');
            element.bind('click', function(){
                actionCode = scope.actionInstance.actionCode;
                //do something
            })
        }
        else{//action on parent element of directive need to apply

            element.parent().on('click', function () {
                console.log('Parent div has action');
            })
        }
        function isViewAssociatedWithAction(){
            return (scope.actionInstance.showActionLabel || scope.actionInstance.showActionIcon) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: if you share code you written to get parent element may help more. you can use link: function(scope, eve) {
    var parent = eve.parent()
}

Comment: Give us your code sample?